# Unable to send ping request from one virtual machine to another placed in different subnets but on the same virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, subnet

I am facing an issue in sending the ping request from one virtual machine to another that are placed in different subnets in a same virtual network

Eg Let the 2 virtual machines are HPCES001 and HPCMG001.  These 2 machines are having 2 NIC cards and ip addresses includes  and are placed in 2 subnets

HPCES001 - One nic card (172.16.168.45) is connected to A subnet  and its other nic is connected to subnet B
HPCMG001 - One nic (10.20.30.50) is connected to subnet C and its other interface 172.16.4.50 is connected to subnet B

I am able to send ping request to 172.16.168.45 from HPCMG001 and the opposite is not working. I am unable to ping 10.20.30.50 from HPCES001. I have enabled routing in all the machines, enabled outbound and inbound rules in firewall. Enabled Routing services and ip routing registry but still I am unable to ping to 10.20.30.50 from HPCES001 and its showing as connection timed out. What could be the reason and how can I fix it

Could you please help ?

Comment: If you have two NICs, which one is the primary one? Do the three subnets locate in the same VNet? Do you turn off the firewall inside the Azure VM for a test?

Comment: 10.20.30.50 is the primary. Yes These subnets are located in the same VNet. I didnt turn off the firewall and but I have created rules in the NSGs

Comment: NSG and the firewall inside vm is different. For example， if you have windows vm，you should add rule for icmp inside windows firewall or turn private network firewall off for test.